# What kind of strategy is more efficient: create a new socket or use one already created?

Tags: java, performance, sockets, client-server

I'm working on a Java client-server program. I use a socket to make the connection but I'm not sure about the efficiency. So, this is my question:
every time that I need a connection with a server, is it more efficient to create a new socket or to use the one created for the previous connection?

I think I need a method to verify if the client is already connected.

Comment: In my opinion, it pretty much depends on the re-use of the connection.. maybe have a time limit to determine re-use vs new?

Comment: the server operations are always the same, sometimes that need more time to elaborate the result, but just this. So, client send input information, and server returns the output result to the client. After, the client user should decide if make again the same operation or close the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of performance is more efficient re-using a previously created socket. But this don't need to be the best solution, it depends on each case.

The idiom case is having a `ServerSocket` in the server side that returns a `Socket` each time a new client connects to to it. If you require multiple clients to work against the server you  could create a `Thread` to treat each client passing it the returned `Socket`.

Moreover, you don't need a method to verify you have a client already connected, `ServerSocket` returns a new `Socket` each time it happens.

Please, read more about this topic in [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

Comment: i already use Thread in server, but i need a method to verify the socket on the client in case i decide to maintain open the connection.
Maybe i was inaccurate on my description, sorry.

Comment: if you don't get any exception, you socket is open. that's all.